# User interactions with answer posting textarea

Tags: support, markdown, editor

When I try to make a particular word or sentence within the post answer text area **Bold** it looks like this:

```
my first sentence
```

But when I try to make more of the sentence bold, e.g.:

```
my first sentence and second
```

I am presented with:

```
**my first sentence** and second**
```

Is it possible to avoid this without direct user interaction like deleting the old selection? I think it is possible by checking the last ** symbol of particular selected sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of the same reason why XHTML has been created after HTML: force the person who is writing a question (or a web page for HTML) to write it in a valid and correct way. It doesn't ask too much effort, and instead of being the SE developers who always do the work for others, let's all contribute (community yay) and make this place one of well-written questions and answers. We already have to be thankful for all the tools that are given to us.

So yes, if you want the whole sentence to be bold, **you will have to put the ** at the right place**.

If not, posts would become really harder to read and maintain (for the edits for example).